# Windows 8: every folder becomes read-only and I cannot change them

Tags: windows-8

I've installed Windows 8 Enterprise on my PC but, all of the folders are read-only and I cannot seem to reverse this. Methods I've tried:

1. Changing its attribute from folder properties.
2. Allowing full control and modify from file properties/security.
3. Changing its attribute from CMD with this command: `attrib -r +s c:\test`
4. Enabling inheritance from advanced security.

All of them have **failed**. I cannot install any software on my PC and I cannot even activate Windows. It would be appreciated if you could help fix this issue.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it has absolutely *nothing* to do with programming.

Comment: One for SuperUser, I think

Comment: @user1935611 - Do you have a real Windows 8 Enterprise license?  I strongly suggest you just simply reinstall Windows 8 to resolve this problem.

Comment: It is my understanding that all folders in an NTFS system are read-only by default. This is an *attribute* not a *permission*. I think you have another issue here.

Comment: I cannot reinstall it because Microsoft Office Pro is installed on this machine with product key. I don't wanna lose it.

Comment: I've upgraded it to Windows 8.1 and the problem still exists.

Comment: no working solution?

Answer (score 1):

I think this might help you.

In Windows, folders cannot be set as read-only. Only the files in the folders can be.

If the read-only box for the folder looks with a dot in it, then it is only the default neutral setting for windows 8.

Only when you check the box with a right symbol, and click on OK ,then the files in the folder will be set as read-only. This only displays temporarily while setting it.

If you have the box empty and click on OK, then all files in the folder will be set as not read-only. This only displays temporarily while setting it.